# How to re-install missing com.intellij.properties and JUnit plugins after crash

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, junit, intellij-plugin

IntelliJ IDEA frequently causes my computer to hang, and after a reset, the IDE loses all of its settings, which I have to re-import. Usually I can keep working after that, but this time, after a crash during the update to `2016.2.2 IC-162.1628.40` last night, IntelliJ seems to have lost the `com.intellij.properties`, `org.intellij.groovy` and `JUnit` plugins.

Here is a screenshot of the event log on startup:

[image: Event log]

I doubt that IntelliJ have decided to limit JUnit tests to only their Ultimate edition in the latest update, so I'm not sure why that last message come up.

I was unable to find the JUnit plugin in both the normal and JetBrains plugin repositories in the settings.

[image: Jetbrains plugin repository]

How do I get these plugins back?

Answer (score 0):

I just re-installed IntelliJ IDEA. It was the easiest solution, and the 'silent install' option which preserved my settings meant I didn't have to do anything else. Now if I can just figure out how to stop it from hanging my computer.....